# Multi line string in EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I want to save some javascript into a variable and put it all into a single script tag

Simplified form:

```
<% let code=``; -%>
<% for (let i=0;i<2;i++){ -%>
    <% code+=` -%>
        <% alert(${i}); -%>
    <% `; -%>
<% } -%
```

...

```
<script>
    <%- code %>
</script>
```

But I get this strange output:

```
; __line = 14
;  alert(0); 
; __line = 15
...
```

My actual usage with no multi line strings ;( :

```
<% code+=`document.getElementById("${i}c").addEventListener("click",()=>{\n` -%>
    <% code+=`let el=document.getElementById("${i}");\n` -%>
    <% code+=`let done=Number(el.innerHTML)^1;\n` -%>
    <% code+=`req({data:'completed='+done+'&id_p=${rows[i].id_p}'});\n` -%>
    <% code+=`el.innerHTML=done;\n` -%>
<% code+=`});\n` -%>
```

output:

```
document.getElementById("0c").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let el=document.getElementById("0");
    let done=Number(el.innerHTML)^1;
    req({data:'completed='+done+'&id_p=57'});
    el.innerHTML=done;
});
```

Comment: I get the impression that a post which stays unanswered for a few hours won't be answered at all, I added my actual usage so it might be clearer to anyone what I'm doing and that what I want to avoid is all of these code+= blocks

Comment: Yes I am, the question is specifically about how to do it in it, "EJS" is the engine

Comment: Aren’t the ejs delimiters just delimiters? Why can’t you just wrap a block in the delimiters and use a normal JS multi-line string?

Comment: Because it doesn't appear to be working, at least not how I'm using it.. with a similar non working output like
   ; __append("alert(0);
")